# jquery setinterval and .load only firing once

Tags: jquery

This script used to work just fine and then it stopped working for some reason and I can't see why. It is not getting the changes from `currentmonthscores.php` which is working correctly.

It will load the correct data initially but if there are any changes it does not load them unless I refresh the page.

You can see the [actual html](http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/games/tail-words/currentmonthscores.php) that is being generated from `currentmonthscores.php` here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval( function () {
        $('#currentmonthscores').load('currentmonthscores.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 1000);
});
```

```js
<div id="currentmonthscores"></div>
```

The only thing I could find close to my problem is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838132/jquery-load-function-only-gets-called-once) on stack where this guy mentions an error with using an interval of 1000 with load but he did not provide an answer.

Comment: Check if your `.load` does not overwrites `#currentmonthscores` element. If it removes it, no loading will continue.

Comment: It sounds like the response is being cached, try adding `$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });` before your `setInterval()`

Comment: Check the network tab in the developer tools. Is the request successfully send, what is returned, which status code, ...

Comment: @Andreas getting a status 200 everytime

Comment: I suggest u fire the next request only when the data is returned and successfully loaded in the div. Also move `fadeIn` on 'load` callback.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That was it. It was caching it. Thanks so much. Can you make it an answer so I can vote it please.

Comment: @CesarBielich Glad to help. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the response is being cached, try adding the following before you call `setInterval()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```